# Invalid argument supplied for foreach() PHP

Tags: php

tengo un problema con el checkbox, cuando no selecciono nada me aparece el siguiente error:

Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

en el siguiente codigo:

**aca se declara la variable**

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['extras']))
      $extras = $_REQUEST['extras'];
```

**aca se muestra el contenido**

```
 print ("   <LI>Extras: ");

      foreach ($extras as $extra)
       print ($extra . " ");
      print ("\n");
```

alguno tiene idea de porque sucede esto? no soy un experto en estos temas, recien comienzo si me podria ayudar muchas gracias.

Comment: Realiza un `var_dump` de `$extras` y compartenos por favor ¿qué salida obtienes?

Comment: Aunque no se seleccione nada, es probable que el $_REQUEST esté establecido, aunque en vacío, así que puedes añadir al if empty para asegurarte: if(isset($_REQUEST['extras']) && !empty($_REQUEST['extras']))

Comment: Antes de `if(isset(...))` declara la variable como arreglo vacío `$extras = [];`; también puedes usar una asignación ternaria: `$extras = (isset($_REQUIRE['extras'])) ? $_REQUIRE['extras'] : [];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es por que tu **variable no existe** cuando no seleccionas nada.

Entonces debes comprobarla antes de hacer el ***foreach***.

**EDIT**

Complementando con lo indicado por **@track3r**, también se añade comprobación por si la variable esta vacía.

El código seria el siguiente:

```
if (isset($extras) && !empty($extras)) {
    print ("   <LI>Extras: ");

    foreach ($extras as $extra)
        print ($extra . " ");

    print ("\n");
}
```

Comment: Si quieren validar correctamente, solo les faltaría usar [`is_iterable()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.is-iterable.php), ya que si no lo es `foreach` también daría error.